# Why the image of diagonal morphism closed implies separated.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I'm reading Qing Liu's book chapter 3.2.

He claims that if the image of diagonal morphism is a closed set, then the scheme is separated (Corollary 3.3.5) and omits the proof. It seems that he want to use exercise 3.3.1 and the previous proposition. But I'm confused how to reduce it into affine case.

Corollary 3.3.5: Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a morphsim such  that $\Delta(X)$ is a closed subset of $X\times_YX$. Then $X$ is separated.

Exercise 3.3.1: Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a morphism. We suppose there exist open subsets $Y_i$ of $Y$ such that $X = \cup_if^{-1}(Y)$ and that the restrictions $f:f^{-1}(Y_i)\rightarrow Y_i$ are closed immersions. Then if $f(X)$ is closed in $Y$, we have $f$ is closed immersion.

Proposition 3.4: Any morphism of affine schemes is separated.

The original statements are:

> **Proposition 3.4.** Any morphism of affine schemes $X \rightarrow Y$ is separated. In particular, any affine scheme is separated.
> **Proof** Let $X=\operatorname{Spec} B$ and $Y=\operatorname{Spec} A .$ By construction of $X \times Y X, \Delta$ is induced by the homomorphism $\rho: B \otimes_{A} B \rightarrow B$ defined by $\rho\left(b_{1} \otimes b_{2}\right)=b_{1} b_{2} .$ It is clear that $\rho$ is surjective, and therefore $\Delta$ is a
> closed immersion.
> **Corollary 3.5.** Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of schemes such that $\Delta(X)$ is a closed subset of $X \times_{Y} X .$ Then $f$ is separated.
> **Proof** This is a consequence of the proposition above and Exercise 3.1 .
> **3.1.** Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of schemes. We suppose that there exist open subsets $Y_{i}$ of $Y$ such that $X=\cup_{i} f^{-1}\left(Y_{i}\right),$ and that the restrictions$f: f^{-1}\left(Y_{i}\right) \rightarrow Y_{i}$ are closed immersions. Show that if $f(X)$ is closed in $Y,$ then $f$ is a closed immersion.

Comment: It would help your question a lot if you replaced the content of these images with text in your post (appropriately formatted using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)). Having to click 3 links (especially when one statement is spread over two images) makes it harder than it needs to be for others to answer your question.

Comment: Since my reputation is not high enough, I'm not able to add a picture in my text. I'm sorry for this. I will try to type it later.

Comment: Even if you could add the image directly, it's best to write out text when possible: see for instance [Why are images of text, code, and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged) on meta.SE.

Comment: It's the fisrt time for me to use mathstackchange. I will type my questions in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $X=\cup_i{U_i}$ as a reunion of affine subschemes, with $f(U_i)$ being contained in an affine subscheme $V_i$ of $Y$.

Then apply Exercise 3.3.1 to the map $\Delta$ and the open subsets of the base $U_i \times_{V_i} U_i$.

Comment: I think I'm not so familar with the explicit construction of fibered product. Does this mean if we have $f:X\rightarrow Z$ and $g:Y\rightarrow Z$ such that $f(X)\subseteq U$ and $g(Y)\subseteq U$, then $X\times_ZY = X\times_UY$?

Comment: Equality is always tricky in terms of schemes... but the natural map $X \times_U Y \rightarrow X \times_Z Y$ is indeed an isomorphism. To show this, you only need to use the universal property.

Comment: Yeah. I see it. I think with this property, my question will be trivial. Thank you for your help!